# Why does my 3-way dimmer circuit show low voltage on one traveler or the other?

Tags: wiring, switch

I have a 3 way dimmer that was wired incorrectly, with you currently having to have the switches thrown in the correct order to get them to work. In trying to work this out, I have been able to determine which 2 wires are the Travelers by using the other switch to isolate them. My question/concern is that when one traveler wire shows 120v, the other traveler wire shows about 50v, and they swap when the other switch is thrown. Is this normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed normal. Modern, high-impedance voltmeters can measure voltage that has no actual "oomph" behind it. What you are seeing is a capacitive "phantom" voltage coupled to the inactive traveler from the active one.  If you have a Low-Z range on your voltmeter, it will indeed not show this "phantom" voltage, nor will it be indicated by an electrical voltage tester ("wiggy" or equivalent device).